# C++ validation using dowhile

Tags: c++, validation, loops, do-while

This is my code, but if the user enters one of the values being checked for, it picks up the error, but displays the error message in a infinite loop

```
std::cin >> withdrawAmount;
    do
    {
        if (withdrawAmount < balance && withdrawAmount > 0)
        {
        break;
        }
    std::cout << "Error: You have insufficient balance to withdraw " << withdrawAmount << " pounds. Your balance is only " << balance << " pounds." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Or you have entered a non positive integer" << std::endl;
    }
    while (true);

// some more code
```

whereas this code, which to works correctly, looks the same to me

```
std::cout << "Please enter todays date: (as an integer) ";
    do
    {
    std::cin >> date;   
        if (date > 1 && date < 31)
        {
        break;
        }
    std::cout << "Error: Please enter todays date: (as an integer) ";
    }
    while (true);

// some more code
```

Also if someone could show me how to add validation to check what they have entered is in fact an integer (not 'two' for example that would be awesome)

Comment: okay, stupid mistake, cin was outside the loop, fixed that, however still can't figure out how to check for an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your main question the cin is outside the loop so it only occurs once.

For your second question call the [fail()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail) memeber function of std::cin after the extraction.